# Can't find an RSA key at my Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have an Ubuntu instance on Amazon EC2. I can login to it via ssh. Also I have:

```
$ ls ~/.ssh/
authorized_keys
```

However, the rsa key itself doesn't exist. Where can I find it? So I'll be able to add it on my github account and pull a repo from it.

Comment: You haven't created one.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

The public half of the keypair is *inside* that file.

```
cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The private half is whatever key you used with SSH to connect to the instance.

Comment: I think you misread the question. The user is asking where the instance's SSH key is so they can add the public key to Github and pull their repo from the instance. In reality they probably want to either generate an SSH key with `ssh-keygen` or forward their own keys into the SSH session with `ssh -A`